# Heroku: How to push seeds.rb to existing rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I store all my app's data in seeds.rb locally. However, after I pushing everything to Heroku, the app works well, but without any data. I do not want to re-input the mass data again, so does anyone have any ways to help me?

Comment: Is there a problem pushing seeds.rb to heroku?

Comment: @CoderSpinoza I am very new to rails app and heroku. I am not sure if the seeds.rb has been pushed to heroku or not. Do you mean that in normal case, the seeds.rb should be pushed to heroku automiticatlly by: 'git push heroku master' and 'heroku run rake db:migrate' without any more action?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you push the app to heroku, you can seed the database with the following command.

```
heroku run rake db:seed
```

Comment: rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)

Answer (score 24):

If you  have changed migrations then first you need to do is run migration

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

then

```
heroku run rake db:seed
```

If you don't have any data in database the I would suggest following is, But caution it will remove all current data from heroku database.

```
heroku run rake db:setup
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

you have to be sure no migration is pending
if no pending

just do

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

and it will word perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add, because I haven't seen it yet.
`heroku run rails db:seed`
Will accomplish the same task.