# Rails App works fine in development but on Heroku postgres causes trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I have a Rails App perfectly working in development and well tested. When deployed on heroku  there is no problem reported, but the app won't work anyway. Opening it in the browser only delivers:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>   If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."

In the log I see a pg expression which works on my variable/table "countries" although I am not too familiar with the meaning:

```
app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod

app[web.1]:                 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d

app[web.1]:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"countries"'::regclass

app[web.1]:                  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped

app[web.1]:                ORDER BY a.attnum

app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:15:in `default_or_selected_country'

app[web.1]: 

heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=evening-refuge-96756.herokuapp.com request_id=a240125e-4115-40d4-bfb0-ade1b8c909d6 fwd="178.165.130.180" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=204ms status=500 bytes=1714
```

I see that my method `default_or_selected_country' is involved. The respective code is unproblematic in development and test mode:

```
def default_or_selected_country
  session[:country_id] ||= Country.find_by(abbreviation: "AT").id
  @default_or_selected_country = Country.find(session[:country_id]).name
end
```

While I am writing this post more similar pg expressions are logged, always containing the "countries" table and also pointing to the same method as above.

Where is my problem and how can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: 1. Run migrations on Heroku if you didn't 2. Restart server.

Comment: Are you sure you have data inside countries table?

Comment: Thanks, [Sebin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1684772/sebin), that is exactly it!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed my app needs some data seeded initially since controllers are pulling it to populate drop-down selectors. Locally this is done by

```
rake db:seed
```

On Heroku it is simply done by

```
heroku run --app APP rake db:seed
```

as written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233414/how-to-push-seeds-rb-to-existed-rails-app-on-heroku) using just the same seeds.rb as locally.