# heroku run rake:db migrate not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I have added, committed and pushed my work to my git repository, then ran the commands below:

```
git push heroku master
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku restart
```

When I check the production site, the data from the development environment has not transferred. I have also included `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production` in my gemfile. Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: Why did you expect data to be copied?

Answer (score 1):

Data can be transferred from development to production by placing the data into the seed.rb file then running the following command:

```
heroku run rake db:setup
```

Be careful because the previous data will be dropped.

[How to push seeds.rb to existing rails app (on Heroku)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233414/how-to-push-seeds-rb-to-existed-rails-app-on-heroku)

Comment: Still this won't copy any of your development data. Just the seeds. Maybe you _were_ asking how to seed the DB, but didn't know the term. Hard to say.

Comment: Nope, I just wanted to transfer from one environment to the other. It just happened to be that the data was in the database. Moving it the seed file allowed me to accomplish the ultimate goal.

Comment: While working, that's a wrong approach to achieving this goal. seeds.rb really has a specific purpose and it is not this. I would dump local database and upload it to heroku's pg directly.

Answer (score 0):

> the data from the development environment has not transferred

Yes, data is not copied (by default). The only changes applied are those in your migrations. If you only create tables/add columns/etc, then only these things will happen. If you create/change records in migrations (so called "data migration"), then that is going to happen. Your development database is NEVER copied.